# Myapp::Application::Railties constant missing with Rails 4 beta and Jruby jruby-1.7.2

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, ruby-on-rails-4

I couldn't get jruby to work with Rails 4 without a hack:

In railties/lib/rails/engine.rb, I had to initialize Railties with const_get, otherwise

```
def railties
  @railties ||= self.class.const_get(:Railties).new
  # @railties ||= self.class::Railties.new
 end
```

Otherwise I get this:

./bin/rake
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Myapp::Application::Railties
org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2677:in `const_missing'
/Volumes/Opt/rails/rails-edge/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in`railties'
/Volumes/Opt/rails/rails-edge/railties/lib/rails/application.rb:241:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/Volumes/Opt/rails/rails-edge/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb:444:in`load_tasks'
org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1659:in `__send__'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2086:in`send'
/Volumes/Opt/rails/rails-edge/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Volumes/Opt/projects/myapp/Rakefile:6:in`(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046:in `load'

Rails itself won't start up for the same reason.  Is this the correct fix or did I mask some underlying problem?

Comment: I'm also seeing this in jruby 1.7.3

Comment: I have jruby 1.7.4.dev installed and same thing - Rails won't start NameError: uninitialized constant MyAppName::Application::Railties

Comment: solved (see answer below)

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't really solve the problem but I added

```
Rails::Engine.class_eval do
  def railties
    @railties ||= self.class.const_get(:Railties).new
  end
end
```

under `Bundler.require` in `application.rb` to avoid having to change the original files.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been fixed with this commit to Rails master (small change to engine): https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/45aabe61520cbb4bd74f6de7dc1023d2ca071e40

I just added:

```
gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
```

or just

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
```

to my Gemfile to pull down the latest version of Rails, and that did the trick.  Was able to delete Alex's (nice - thankyou!) hack and it all works as it should.